# git alias always runs git in current dir

Tags: bash, git

I use git worktrees. They're great, but have one limitation: only 1 worktree can have any given branch checked out at any time. As a result, I often find myself in some worktree or another and I want to change to master but `git checkout master` fails as another worktree already has it checked out. So I whipped up this handy alias:

```
[alias]
    parkall = "!git -C $(git worktree list | grep master | cut -d' ' -f1) checkout -b parked-$(date +%Y-%M-%dT%H.%m.%S)"
```

The `git worktree list | grep master | cut -d' ' -f1` returns the name of the directory holding the worktree with `master` checkout out so this is the equivalent of

```
parkall = "!git -C some/woktree/path checkout -b parked-$(date ...)"
```

and it runs OK, but the `-C` argument is ignored; it always runs as if `-C` wasn't given so instead of moving the worktree with `master` checked out to a `parked-...` directory it moves my current worktree there. I also tried a shell script:

````
```sh
#!/bin/bash

master_dir=$(git worktree list | grep master | cut -d' ' -f1)

if [[ -n $master_dir ]]
then
   cd $master_dir
   echo "cd'd to:" $master_dir
   pwd
   git checkout -b parked-$(date +%Y-%M-%dT%H.%m.%S)
fi
````

That works as expected if I run it directly. However, if I change my alias to:

```
parkall = !~/bin/git_park.sh
```

It still `echo`s the correct information but it again ignores the `-C` and changes the branch of my current worktree.

It seems that if you're running a Git alias a number of environment variables are set. In particular, [`GIT_DIR`, which sets the directory holding `.git`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables) is set. It seems like that would cause the issue I'm seeing but updating my script to unset all the `GIT_` environment variables doesn't work:

```bash
#!/bin/bash


master_dir=$(git worktree list | grep master | cut -d' ' -f1)

# When run via a git alias git sets several environment variables which can mess things up. Unset them.
for ev in $(env)
do
   ev=${ev%=*}
   if [[ $ev =~ ^GIT_ ]]
   then
      env -u $ev
   fi
done

if [[ -n $master_dir ]]
then
   echo "Parking $master_dir"
   git -C $master_dir checkout -b parked-$(date +%Y-%M-%dT%H.%m.%S)
fi
```

Even stranger, changing the `-C` argument to `--git-dir` returns an error that the directoy I've passed isn't a git directory though it clearly is.

EDIT:

Per @jay's comment, `env -u` doesn't remove the variable from the environment, just from the `env` output. Changing that to `unset` did the trick:

```bash
#!/bin/bash


master_dir=$(git worktree list | grep master | cut -d' ' -f1)

# When run via a git alias git sets several environment variables which can mess things up. Unset them.
for ev in $(env)
do
   ev=${ev%=*}
   if [[ $ev =~ ^GIT_ ]]
   then
      unset $ev
   fi
done

if [[ -n $master_dir ]]
then
   echo "Parking $master_dir"
   git -C $master_dir checkout -b parked-$(date +%Y-%M-%dT%H.%m.%S)
fi
```

Comment: BTW, you're quoting the wrong things. `cd "$master_dir"`, `echo "cd'd to: $master_dir"`, etc -- constant strings don't need to be quoted unless they contain shell syntax; parameter expansions, command substitutions, etc need to be double-quoted because you can't tell ahead-of-time whether they contain glob characters, whitespace, or other things that will cause extra parsing steps at runtime in absence of quotes. This is a class of problems that https://shellcheck.net/ will catch.

Comment: As another aside -- if you only need to support recent versions of bash, think about using `printf -v branch_name 'parked-%(%Y-%m-%dT%H.%m.%S)T' -1` as a faster, shell-builtin alternative to the `date` command.

Comment: As for the problem you're running into, btw -- dump the environment variables that are set when you're running as an alias. You'll see git adds quite a lot under the `GIT_*` namespace; one of them will be the culprit.

Comment: As far as I understand `env -u VARNAME` only unsets the variable in its output, it does **not** unset the variable in the environment of the shell that invoked `env`.
Maybe try `unset VARNAME` to unset the variable. Also: those are probably exported variables and will be passed down to `git` regardless, unless you also do `export -n VARNAME` etc.

Comment: On another note: I failed to reproduced the issue locally. `git version 2.30.2` on Devuan Linux. I used `git log`, not `git checkout` for testing though. So maybe checkout behaves differently when it comes to worktrees and the `-C` param.

Comment: @Jay you were correct! `env -u` does not actually remove it from the environment despite the man page saying, "remove variable from the environment". Anyway, changing to `unset` did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach of cleaning up the environment before calling git seems fine,
but: `env -u VARNAME` cannot be used that way, as it only unsets the variable in its output or in the environment of the command passed as argument (if any).
It does *not* unset the variable in the environment of the shell that invoked `env`.

Try `unset VARNAME` to unset the variable instead.

Also: In case those are exported variables, they might get passed down to git regardless, unless you also do `export -n VARNAME` to remove their export-flag.

---

With regards to `env`'s man-page:

I also read the "remove variable from the environment" part there.

But after some initial confusion I figured that probably isn't supposed to mean the invoking shell's environment.

The reason for that is that `env` is a binary and not a bash built-in command (see `type env`).

So sure, `env`, like any other program, can change its own environment and the environment of the processes it spawns (which is actually its main purpose).

But I would not expect it to be able/designed to change the environment of the process it was called by (in this case: bash).

(I then did some tests to confirm my suspicion)

Unsetting the variables while invoking git, using `env -u VARNAME git checkout ...` should work fine :)